# Populate data in <div> after retrieving through ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

My view clearly returns the data as I desired, but thing is that I'am unable to load this data into a particular div, I have shown the div tag below.

**My views looks like this**

```
def pop_user(request, username): 
    print('user')
    data = dict()
    profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    context = {'profile': profile}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('profile/pop_user.html',
            context,
            request=request,
            )
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**My js/ajax is like this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('.user').hover(function (e) { 
          // alert($(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url"))
         var offset = $(this).offset();
         var left = e.pageX;

         var top = e.pageY;
         var theHeight = $('#myPopoverContent').height();
         $('#myPopoverContent').show();
         $('#myPopoverContent').css('left', (left+10) + 'px');
         $('#myPopoverContent').css('top', (top-(theHeight/2)-10) + 'px');

          $.ajax({
            url: $(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url") +"/",
            type: 'get',
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
            $("#myPopoverContent").html(data.html_form);
            }
          });


     });


     $('#myPopoverContent').focusin(function (e) {
         $('#myPopoverContent').active();
       });

    $('#myPopoverContent').mouseout(function (e) {
         $('#myPopoverContent').hide();
       }); 
    $('.user').mouseout(function (e) {
         $('#myPopoverContent').hide();
       });          
  });
```

**And my html is**

```html
<div id="myPopoverContent" class="dealBg"> 

</div>
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(data.html_form)` in our success callback?

Comment: What's not working? What do you see instead?

Comment: Where is `form` defined? No element having `class` attribute set to `"username"` appears at HTML

Comment: And why not  `$("#myPopoverContent").load($(this).closest(".username").attr("data-url") +"/")`

Comment: when i hit this url I get json data which is my requirement, but after success function in ajax, i want to display this in <div id="myPopoverContent" class="dealBg"> 

</div>

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov console.log.log(data.html_form) gives a html page which is my requirement. Problem is only that Im unable to display that data.html_form in my desired div :(

Comment: And if you comment out the hide?

Comment: @mplungjan I already tried that, didn't worked :(

Comment: @Jorg everything fine but data which is returned is not displayed in desired <div>

Comment: @guest271314 attribute for username is set from different page, and I don't think that might cause any problem because ajax is returning data as desired. Only problem is data is not displayed in desired <div>

Comment: Do you have other id="myPopoverContent" elements on the page? If so that is not allowed. IDs must be unique

Comment: @mplungjan confirmed, there no other such id used.

Comment: One issue could be that `$.ajax()` is asynchronous. The request takes time to process. Are you sure `.mouseout()` is not called?

Comment: Im not using .mouseout() function in fact.  I was just testing with that function. Now im free with mouseout()

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to figure out the problem. I got it done. :)